# Counting frequencies from categorical data by group where data frame is in wide format

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, reshape, data-wrangling

I have a patient dataset. Two groups of patients with several categorical variables include gender, medication and medication conditions (comorbidities). The example below is a  fictitious dataset to represent my dataset.

I would like to create a table and then a plot (in ggplot2) to illustrate the proportion of each medication and comorbidities.

```
group <- sample(c("group 1 ", "group 2"), 100, replace = TRUE)
gender <-  sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE)
medication_1 <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace=TRUE)
medication_2 <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace=TRUE)
comorbidity_1 <-sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace=TRUE)
comorbidity_2 <-sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(group, gender, medication_1, medication_2, comorbidity_1, comorbidity_2)
```

I have tried to use reshape to change the data frame from wide to long but then get stuck.

```
library(reshape)
df_m <- melt(df, id=c("group"))

df_m %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(count_var =n())
```

I want to achieve a table that lists the count of each medication and comorbidities present and then split by the group. From here, I want to create a plot as presented by Julia (https://juliasilge.com/blog/bird-baths/) to illustrate the difference in proportion per group.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this fits your need. First, you have to include `gender` in the `id` when reshaping. Second, you have to filter you data for `Yes` answers. Afterwards you could use `dplyr::count` to get the counts and use `ggplot2` to make your chart like so:

```r
library(reshape)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

df_m <- melt(df, id = c("group", "gender"))

df_m %>%
  filter(value == "Yes") %>%
  count(group, variable) %>%
  ggplot(aes(n, variable)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = variable)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = group))
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(1)

group <- sample(c("group 1 ", "group 2"), 100, replace = TRUE)
gender <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE)
medication_1 <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
medication_2 <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
comorbidity_1 <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
comorbidity_2 <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(group, gender, medication_1, medication_2, comorbidity_1, comorbidity_2)
```